# TestNG not Compatible with Eclipse Luna and Eclipse Indigo

Tags: java, selenium, testng, eclipse-luna, eclipse-indigo

I installed TestNG in Eclipse Luna and Eclipse Indigo but TestNG is not showing in the preferences window. I followed right step 2 times as mentioned at below link

http://www.guru99.com/all-about-testng-and-selenium.html

It is giving me the same problem in both versions of Eclipse... Any suggestion how to start working with TestNG?

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: @HelpingHands I am not getting any error....

Comment: But when i see in Perferences there is option of TestNG and also no option in "Run as" option

Comment: Did you installed TESTNG to eclipse properly?

Comment: Yes .. I followed the steps mentioned in  above link

Comment: I installed Eclipse Keepler.. It's working with TestNG fine :)....

test Cases are getting Failed

Comment: great..what you mean by `test Cases are getting Failed`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55000314/eclipse-invalid-classpath-container-testng-in-project-and-junit-failed/59646795#59646795

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue with eclipse 2019-06 using the marketplace.

I could install TestNG using Help->Install new software...

The update site to fill into *Work with* was http://beust.com/eclipse for me.

Comment: Not sure if it was a copy/paste mistake or the https in the link, but the same link at https://testng.org/doc/download.html did not work. Maybe it was something simple like I had a space in beginning, but your answer works.

Answer (score 0):

I see, the question is quite old but I faced the same symptoms. For me the solution to this problem was to upgrade my Java installation from 1.6 to 1.8. After that the TestNG pluggin worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Only these versions of Eclipse are supported now
**Eclipse Versions:** 
Oxygen (4.7), Neon (4.6), Mars (4.5), Luna (4.4), Kepler (4.3), Juno (4.2, 3.8), Previous to Juno (<=4.1), Photon (4.8), 2018-09 (4.9)
**Java Version:** Java 1.7+ is required for running the TestNG for Eclipse plugin.
For any update follow this link:
https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/testng-eclipse

Answer (score 0):

May be late to the Party but this works for me:

```
Install from update site
Select Help / Install New Software...
Enter the update site URL in "Work with:" field:
Update site for release: https://dl.bintray.com/testng-team/testng-eclipse-release/.
Make sure the check box next to URL is checked and click Next.
Eclipse will then guide you through the process.
```

[Link](https://testng.org/doc/download.html)

Answer (score 0):

**For me this worked**

**I have installed latest version of the eclipse.**

**To install TestNG**

**`Go to help->`**

[image]

**`Then Install new software->`**

[image]

**`Next enter this url`** : https://testng.org/testng-eclipse-update-site

[image]

`Next stpes you will get to know`

`Enter the url and click on add It prompts a dialogue  there enter the "TestNG" then again enter the url add -> accept the certificate and booom you are good to use.`

Answer (score -1):

Had to install eclipse 2018-09(4.9.0) to resolve the 'TestNG not compatible with the eclipse version' issue.
With Java 1.8

Comment: Hi there, this doesn't really seem like a question, more like a statement. What is it that you need to know?

Comment: It is not a question. It is the solution I found.
When I faced the 'TestNG not compatible with the eclipse version' issue, I had to uninstall the latest versions of eclipse and go with eclipse 2018-09(4.9.0) to find TestNG in Eclipse Marketplace.

Comment: @Tijo no need to go back to previous version, there are many way to install testng in latest eclipse aswell.  EX: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72404981/9939807