# Unable to install TestNG from eclipse marketplace?

Tags: java, eclipse, installation, testng, testng-eclipse

When I am trying to install the TESTNG from the eclipse market place, I am getting the following errors:

HTTP proxy authentication required: http://beust.com/eclipse/content.xml.

Even I have tried to install the TestNG from eclipse Install New Software using the URL "http://beust.com/eclipse" throwing the same error. I tried appending "/" after the eclipse in the URL. I also tried using https. I tried installing from the market place as well. But no luck!! Same error thrown.Somebody please help me. Test NG Installation error in eclipse. I have attached the screen shots.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xIBo2.jpg)

Comment: There's an issue with Eclipse's TestNG installation, see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55000314/eclipse-invalid-classpath-container-testng-in-project-and-junit-failed

Comment: The URL redirects to `http://dl.bintray.com/testng-team/testng-eclipse-release/`. Does using this URL work? If not, are you behind a proxy? If so, check your setting in _Window > Preferences: General > Network Connections_.