# TestNG not compatible with eclipse 2019-09

Tags: eclipse, installation, eclipse-plugin, testng

I recently installed Eclipse Oxygen version 2019-09 and trying to install TestNG, also searched on Eclipse Marketplace, and tried to install it by drag and drop method, but its is giving me following error.
I also tried adding an external JAR for TestNG 'testng-6.9.10'.
Please help me with the method to install the same.[Error while adding TestNG.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQYun.jpg)
[Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLjsW.jpg)

Comment: SEE https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55000314/eclipse-invalid-classpath-container-testng-in-project-and-junit-failed

Comment: I have problem with installation.

Comment: Note: 2019-09 is **not** Eclipse Oxygen - its name is just '2019-09', Oxygen is a much older release.

Comment: If you look at the market place entry [here](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/testng-eclipse) the last version it lists as compatible is 2018-09 and there are plenty of comments saying it doesn't work with anything later. The comments there suggest other places to try.

Comment: Use maven, do not download yourself the jars or use Intellij Community, it's free.

Answer (score 1):

To solve the problem, I just updated my Eclipse by checking the software updates from <kbd>Eclipse</kbd> > <kbd>help</kbd> > <kbd>Check for updates</kbd>.

Then I was able to install TestNG for Eclipse, which solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the `Check for updates` solution didn't work with our Eclipse (2019-09), we solved it using `Help\Install New Software` and after that `https://testng.org/testng-eclipse-update-site/`:
[image]